# How can I change a cell's textLabel frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I've tried nearly everything, but I just can't seem to move the cell.textLabel property down a little bit. I've attached a screenshot below and I've tried nearly everything I could find.

I've tried changing the .frame property directly, attempted at modifying if via using the "- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell" method". I've also tried allocating a custom label. I could move the custom label, but it wouldn't go into separate lines like the original textLabel. I just need to move the pictured multi line label a bit down.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only way to do this is to use a `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `-layoutSubviews`. In this method, you'll want to call `[super layoutSubviews]`, and then do any frame tweaks that you want to the label.

Answer (score 22):

override `layoutSubviews` for your `UITableViewCell`...

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4.0f, 4.0f, size.width, size.height); 
    self.textLabel.frame =  frame;
    self.textLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

or you can simply make your own UILabel object, and add it to cell.contentView as a subview.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 30, 30)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding a \n in the beginning of the string. Unfortunately I couldn't get anything else to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(4.0f, 4.0f, size.width, size.height); 
    self.textLabel.frame =  frame;

    self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code does, and why it answers the question ?