# Trouble with putting label in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use this code to display `UITableView` with 2 segment

```
if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {

        firstSeg=[firsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString * celldata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@",firstSeg.a,firstSeg.b,firstSeg.c];

        lbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20) ];

        lbl.text=celldata;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];   
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

        seconSeg=[secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString * celldata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@",secondSeg.a,secondSeg.b,secondSeg.c];

        lbl2 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20) ];

        lbl2.text=celldata;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl2];
        }


    return cell;
```

My `tableView` and my segment work fine , but when I select a row in the second segment, the first label `lbl` and `lbl2` appear together. I tried, in the second segment, to make `lbl=nil`, `lbl=NULL` but it don't work, can you help me please?

---

with this 
cell.textLabel.text =celldata;
it woek perfectly but the text is too large, i can't modifie the size ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are adding the label to the cell every time you reload the tableview cells

Try adding the label only once and specify a tag for this label

add at the top of your file:

```
#define CELL_LABEL_TAG 333
```

when you create the cell, create also the label and add it as a subview

```
UILabel *lbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 20) ];
[lbl setTag:CELL_LABEL_TAG];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
```

Change your code to:

```
if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {

    firstSeg=[firsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString * celldata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@",firstSeg.a,firstSeg.b,firstSeg.c];

    lbl =(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_LABEL_TAG];

    lbl.text=celldata;
}
else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {

    seconSeg=[secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString * celldata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@  %@",secondSeg.a,secondSeg.b,secondSeg.c];

    lbl2 =(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_LABEL_TAG];

    lbl2.text=celldata;
    }


return cell;
```

Comment: sorry but i habent understand your code .. i updated my question , i will juste use  cell.textLabel.text

Comment: I understand that you want to change the default cell text label, right? look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824973/how-can-i-change-a-cells-textlabel-frame

Comment: The code I posted allow you to add a custom label once, and then find it by its tag and use it again

Comment: thank you but i should create CELL_LABEL_TAG2 for lbl2 ? i tird this code and i alwayse have the same problem ..

Comment: I think you don't need to have lbl and lbl2, you need only to create a new label with new cells, and no need to add this label as an instance variable.  As your cells have the same layout, use only one tag, and if your cells are have different layout, try using two reuse cell identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have many cells, allocate a new `UITableViewCell` object instead of reusing cells.
That could solve your problem.

And release the labels after adding them as a subview!

Comment: i haven't understand you answer too :p