# how to modifie text size in UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i haven't found a solution for this answer
[Trouble with putting label in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322309/trouble-with-putting-label-in-uitableview)
so i will put a string in my cell . But the string is too larg , how can modifie the size of the string in the cell ? 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:10.0];
```

You can tweak the `size:` to achieve the right size.