# Apply offset to UILabel text baseline? It is a label of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nstableview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITableView` that with some cells that contains only some text. The text in the cells is vertically aligned to the center of the cell but it does not look good because of the font used. The text appears to be shifted a bit up.

I need to adjust the baseline of the text so that the text really appears to be in the center (vertically) of the cells.

The text is set in following way:

```
cell.textLabel.text = //some text
```

What I tried so far:

1. Adjust `frame` property of the label (`cell.textlabel`) - add offset to y coordinate. Did not work I think because I reuse cells and the frame is recalculated before the cell is displayed.
2. Use custom `UILabel` instead of `cell.textLabel` and add it as a subview of the cell. This did not work well when `UITableView` was set to edit mode - the custom `UILabel`s did not adjust their frame when red - deletion icons were show.
3. I tried to set `cell.textLabel.attributedText` instead of `cell.textLabel.text` and use `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute to set an offset. However although XCode recognizes all other attribute names this one is not recognized with error *Use of undefined identifier NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName*. The constant is not marked as deprecated anywhere  but in iOS 6.0 SDK release notes I have found that *Due to compatibility concerns, the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute is no longer supported in iOS 6.*

Any suggestions how to apply baseline offset to text contained in table cells are very welcome. Solution is required to be compatible with iOS SDK 6.0 and compatibility with iOS SDK 7.0 is nice to have.

Comment: Only answer on this question was copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824973/how-can-i-change-a-cells-textlabel-frame