# why my dynamic prototypes cell overlapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I use dynamic prototypes, I found my label is overlapping.

"firstLabel" is the default text of the label I have inserted on storyboard and I set the text "ios" when the program run.

Following are my code.

```
@implementation ViewController{
    NSArray* _books;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _books=@[@"ios",@"android"];
    self.table.dataSource=self;
    self.table.delegate=self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger row=indexPath.row;
    NSString* cellID=(row%2==0?@"cell1":@"cell2");
    UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel* label=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text=_books[row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _books.count;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 80;
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: Check the UILabel tag and set it to 1

Comment: I've set it to 1 in storyboard

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: i'm not using it

Comment: does your code calling "heightForRowAtIndexPath" every time?

Comment: No.Even i don't override it,mistake also happens

Comment: are you using custom cell?

Comment: @PPL i use dynamic prototypes.i didn't inherit UITableViewCell

Comment: @Qyy why you want to use two different cellIDs? if you want just color change then you can simply do it also

Comment: @PPL okay, I use one cellID now and it gets right. But if I want to use different custom cell what should I do?

Comment: @Qyy create custom cell with different class

Comment: It seems like you address to another label / cell each time. How is the storyboard looks?

Comment: @PPL thank you. Is it just like this: if(row==1){XXUITableViewCell* cell=.....}else{YYUITableViewCell* cell=.....}

Comment: @JoeRazon thank you. Maybe my two cellIDs is mixed. I set one cellID and it gets right now.

Comment: Great! Glad to help mate. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank everyone for your replies. I found when I use two cellIDs, they maybe mixed. After I set only one cellID, it gets right.

```
NSString* cellID=(row%2==0?@"cell1":@"cell2");
```

change to `NSString* cellID=@"cell1";`

Answer (score -1):

because the firstLabel's height is equal to the cell. and the firstLabel in the above of the custom label.

[image]

Comment: should i set a new height for row?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824973/how-can-i-change-a-cells-textlabel-frame